# How can stream manipulators in C++ be functions?

Tags: c++, manipulators

When calling a function in C++, function's name is written followed by `()` to distinguish it as a function call. Why can't I call **stream manipulator functions** in the same way?

Why this isn't allowed?:

```
cout << "Hello!" << endl();
```

Isn't `endl` a variable holding `\n`?

Thanks!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: So you mean endl is a pointer to a function? :o

Comment: I've taken the "Isn't endl a variable holding \n?" out of the question, because it thoroughly confused me (hence my now-deleted comment), and you seem to already recognise `endl` as a function, not a variable.

Comment: yes, the name of a function can be used as a pointer

Comment: @hvd: don't. that's part of his question. he's confused as well - so he needs explanation for it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The question as it was (and as you've put it back) just plain doesn't make any sense to me. If `endl` is a function, it isn't a variable. If it were a variable, it wouldn't be a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't endl a variable holding \n?

No, it is not. `std::endl` is a function defined in global namespace

```
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
    endl(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os)
    { return flush(__os.put(__os.widen('\n'))); }
```

In expression `std::cout << endl_or_something` right hand side of `<<` is an argument of a call to `operator<<` (first argument is `std::ostream` implicitly). So endl_or_something should be an int, double or other type that can be converted to one of the possible arguments of `operator<<`. There is an overloaded version of this operator that takes pointers to functions ( functions which take reference to `std::ostream` and return reference to `std::ostream`):

```
  // [27.6.2.5] formatted output
  // [27.6.2.5.3]  basic_ostream::operator<<
  //@{
  /**
   *  @brief  Interface for manipulators.
   *
   *  Manipulators such as @c std::endl and @c std::hex use these
   *  functions in constructs like "std::cout << std::endl".  For more
   *  information, see the iomanip header.
  */
  __ostream_type&
  operator<<(__ostream_type& (*__pf)(__ostream_type&))
  {
// _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
// DR 60. What is a formatted input function?
// The inserters for manipulators are *not* formatted output functions.
return __pf(*this);
  }
```

Since `std::endl` signature matches, it can be used in expression

```
std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
```

or equivalently

```
std::cout << "Hello!";
std::endl( std::cout);
```

Note however that this manipulator is often mistakenly used when a simple newline is desired, leading to poor buffering performance. In such cases use just `"\n"`.

---

> Why this isn't allowed?:
>
> ```
> cout << "Hello!" << endl();
> ```

std::endl takes one argument, std::ostream. You can see that it can be called with:

```
return __pf(*this);
```

means

```
return std::endl( *this); // std::endl( std::cout);
```

**There is no version of** `std::endl` **that takes no parameters** so it could be called with

```
std::endl()
```

In expression

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

it denotes an argument to `operator<<`, it is passed as a pointer to function and then called in body of `operator<<`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Does it mean the function `operator<<()` takes in an argument called `endl`  and `endl` is something defined inside <iostream>?

Comment: yes, endl is a function defined in <ostream>, and operator<< takes its name as a pointer to function

Answer (score 3):

Stream manipulators *are* functions. As such, they *can* be called using the call operator `()`. Here's how you would call `std::endl` on a stream:

```c++
std::endl(std::cout);
```

This is the way it would have to be called for each and every stream on which you want to use `std::endl`. This is because `std::endl` is a function that takes a returns a reference to a stream object. This is a very quirky way of doing it, so there is a convenience function to stream line the syntax:

```c++
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& (*manip)(std::ostream&));
```

This is an overload of `operator<<()` that takes a stream on its left hand side and a manipulator on its right hand side. `std::endl` is technically a function, so it can be converted to a function pointer.

Inside the implementation of this overload, `manip` is called pretty much how I just showed you. This allows syntax such as:

```c++
std::cout << "Hello, World" << std::endl;
```

If you went ahead and called `std::endl` using the call operator it will return a reference to the stream. There is another overload of `operator<<()` that takes a `const void*` as its argument. That will be the overload that is inadvertently called.

```c++
std::cout << std::endl(std::cout); // prints a newline then an address
```

Comment: one note: overload of << for manimpualators is ostream member function

Answer (score 2):

Manipulators are functions specifically designed to be used in conjunction with the insertion (<<) and extraction (>>) operators on stream objects, for example:

```
cout << boolalpha;
```

They are still regular functions and can also be called as any other function using a stream object as argument, for example:

```
boolalpha (cout);
```

So, in your code, you can do

```
cout << "Hello!";
endl(cout);
```

instead of

```
cout << "Hello!" << endl;
```

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/).